# Post request returning 405

Tags: python-2.7, http, scrapy

I have to do a post but i am getting error 405

In this website -> http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/# i need iterate over the options of 2 dropdown menus on top of page.

First i do post with the options beside of "Escolha o Exercício:"
Then, i do post with the options beside of "Escolha a Entidade:"

With the code bellow i do the post over "Escolha o Exercício:"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class ScpiSpider(scrapy.Spider): # classe abstrata
    start_urls = ['http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia']

def parse(self, response):
    anos_exercicios = response.xpath("//table[@id='cmbExercicio_DDD_L_LBT']//td/text()").extract()

    for ano in anos_exercicios:
        formadata = {"Scriptmanager1": "UpdatePanel1|cmbExercicio",
                         "cmbExercicio_VI": ano,
                        "cmbExercicio": ano,
                        "__EVENTTARGET": "cmbExercicio",
                        "__VIEWSTATE": response.xpath("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value").get(),
                        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": response.xpath("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value").get(),
                        "__EVENTVALIDATION": response.xpath("//input[@id='__EVENTVALIDATION']/@value").get(),
                         "__ASYNCPOST": "true"}
        headers = {
            'origin': "http://177.125.200.195:8079",
            'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
            'cache-control': "no-cache",
            'x-microsoftajax': "Delta=true",
            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36",
            'accept': "*/*"
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], formdata=formadata, callback=self.parse_entidade,
                                 dont_filter=True, headers=headers)

def parse_entidade(self, response):
    print(response)
```

I expect that code enter in parse_entidade but i am reciving `[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <405 http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a '/' to the start_url seems to be doing the trick:

```
start_urls = ['http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/']
```

Output I get when launching it like this is as follows:

```
2019-08-07 09:44:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/> (referer: None)
2019-08-07 09:44:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/> (referer: http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/)
2019-08-07 09:44:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/> (referer: http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/)
<200 http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/>
<200 http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/>
2019-08-07 09:44:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/> (referer: http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/)
<200 http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/>
2019-08-07 09:44:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/> (referer: http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/)
<200 http://177.66.89.34:8079/Transparencia/>
2019-08-07 09:44:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```